# How to access the arguments of parent function in nested function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I am trying to find the maximum of two numbers using the following code using a nested function in javascript, however, I am encountering the following error in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: maximum is not defined", seems that the nested function val2 is not able to access the argument of function val. Any idea on how can we fix this?

```
function val(maximum)
{
    var val2=new Function('input','if(input>maximum){return("Number is greater");}else{return("Number is less")}');
    return val2;
}

var call=val(5);
console.log(call(2));
```

Comment: Why are you using `val` and `new Function`?

Comment: `function val(max) { return function(input) { return "Number is " + (input > max ? "greater" : "less"); }`

Comment: `const val = maximum => x => x > maximum ? 'Number is greater' : 'Number is less';`

Comment: @Wyck your answer unfortunately doesn't use the nested function which the  op is interested in

Comment: @user2599052: It does, look closely: `maxium => x => ...` . `val` is a function that takes `maximum` as a parameter and returns a function (`x => ...`).

Comment: he is looking to use the syntax `new Function` if you don't understand even know.

Comment: @user2599052: What makes you think that? Why do you think the OPs main objective is to "use new Function" instead of "close over function parameters"? That appears to be your interpretation of the question, but nowhere does the OP say "I want to use `new Function`".

Comment: In that case, let the OP clarify since he appears to be a new user. But how do you know that your interpretation is better than somebody else's

Comment: @user2599052: Obviously I can't know, but I think a good strategy is to make as few assumptions as possible. To me the main part of the question is *"How to access the arguments of parent function in nested function in javascript?"* To achieve that the OP needs to define the function differently. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

> seems that the nested function val2 is not able to access the argument of function val

While you are creating the function inside another one, `new Function` behaves as if the function was created in global scope, i.e. it doesn't have access to the function environment it was created in. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) for more details.

There is no reason to use `new Function`, you can just create the function directly and you will be able to access the outer function's arguments, because every function in JavaScript is a closure:

```js
function val(maximum) {
  return function(input) {
    if (input>maximum){
      return("Number is greater");
    } else {
      return("Number is less");
    }
  };
}

var call=val(5);
console.log(call(2));
```

I hope it goes without saying that this is better than writing code inside a string literal. There is almost never a reason to use `new Function` to create a function.

Answer (score -2):

```
maximum = 5;
function val()
{
    var val2=new Function('input','if(input>maximum){return("Number is greater");}else{return("Number is less")}');
    return val2;
}

var call=val();
console.log(call(2));
```

The above will work. In case you define functions using `new Function`, it doesn't close on the function from where it is created but closes on the global env. That why i have moved maximum outside and it works. You can read about closures for more on this.

Comment: Everyone has their own reasons for downvoting. Not every solution that works is a good solution. The three things that jump out on me that could be considered bad: Use of global variable and pointless use of a wrapper function (`val`) and `new Function`. Why does `val` even exist at this point if it always returns the "same" function? Why is `new Function` being used if nothing about the function is dynamic? I think we can all agree that this is *objectively* bad code and we should hold our answers to higher standards.

Comment: If you mean to imply that the use of `new Function` is required for whatever reason, then the answer should be "you can't access parameters of an 'outer' function when using `new Function`".

Comment: You could have been more explicit, but sure. However, why have you chosen this solution instead of showing how to create a function that closes of outer function's parameters? And btw, I didn't downvote, but I understand why you might think that.

Comment: I'm just defending myself from your accusations and trying to understand your thought process.